# Animating the gap between elements according to their fluid content

Tags: css, animation, width

TL;DR version: I need 3 of [these](http://www.media-division.com/javascript-animated-collapsible-panels-without-frameworks/) side-by-side in a way that their percentage-based widths animate when one opens and has enough data to push the others aside.

---

I have a slim section at the top of my page which must remain resizable and hence its contents have all their width defined as a percentage. Within that section I have 3 elements (actually it's 3 columns of 3 of the panel example, hence 3*3=9 collapsible panels, but as far as I can tell it may as well just be any other div and most solutions would still work the same) which have smoothly animated height as they're clicked on to show their contents.

Additionally, when the panels are opened the width of ALL panels becomes suitable for all panels shown contents, changing the size of the empty space available for each panel accordingly, here's why:

For ease, and because no other solution yet proved more functional thus far, the 3*3 panels are divided into three columns of three panels each in a cell in an invisible table as such:

```
<table>
<tr><td> [3PanelColA] </td><td> [3PanelColB] </td><td> [3PanelColC] </td><tr>
</table>
```

In other words, this works great. Whenever you click on any of the 9 panels, it opens smoothly downwards and the width of all panels (table cells) gets resized perfectly according to how much content is in the shown open panels, and at the same time everything can be resized any time according to the size of the top section (or resizing the browser window). There's just one problem: the panels, at their current stage, while being opened correctly and according to their proper percentage width, animate smoothly downwards, but their width simply snaps into place!

So, I've tried animating the panels sideways at the same time as downwards when they open, I've tried animating the table cells, I've tried putting the panel columns in divs that have animating gaps in-between, I've tried making some kind of accordionception with the vertically opening panels inside of horizontally moving panels, I've tried swapping out the entire layout for other panel systems in hopes it might work better.

I've browsed through and modified countless grid systems in attempts to make something that allows for opening panels with the entire grid changing size both vertically and horizontally accordingly, all just to make the space between the panel columns move smoothly instead of snapping into place.

So long story short, I need 3 parallel columns of 3 expandable panels each, of which their sizes animates smoothly and according to the size of their content, with a percentage width and ability to open/close as many panels as you want any time (all starting out as closed). While I already have some panels that could work and used a simple table to make them 3 by 3, they animate downwards but not sideways.

This example here comes close to what I need (I would just cut it down to 3*3 imageless panels instead of 5*6): http://css-tricks.com/examples/InfoGrid/. It has a grid of panels and whenever you open one it changes the size of all the other ones accordingly, however, the widths are specific and defined in amount of pixels rather than percentages, and it doesn't seem to support opening any desired amount of panels simultaneously no matter what I do to it.

I'm willing to try any approach that you might suggest, just please keep in mind that;

- It has to be 3 by 3 downwards-expandable/collapsible panels which all change size smoothly according to each others displayed contents and can be opened/closed independently of each other
- The sizes (or at least the widths) have to be percentage-based, not fixed amounts of pixels
- If possible, it should use up as little bandwidth and filesize as possible, preferably no more than 15kb

The solution could be as simple as animating the table cells widths when a panel is opened, or putting the panel columns in some kind of divs/elements whose widths/gaps animate when a panel is opened, or using a completely new panel grid system or some such.

Comment: Too many words! Try to trim this down to something more readable.

Comment: Downvote? I already added a TL;DR version starting with "long story short," :( at the same time stackoverflow signup told me to be speciffic

Comment: Definitely need to trim it down and add a JSFiddle with as much code as you can.

Comment: You _added_ a tl;dr? That suggests immediately that the first half of your question is just noise.

Comment: "noise"!? Right before I was allowed to even start writing the post stackoverflow told me:

"Be specific

If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer."

So I did.

Also, speak, I already added all the code, it's a simple table with percentage widths, there's really very little relevant code other than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just threw this together so it is pretty crude, and a prototype, but I think it might be what you're looking for?

```
<div class="wrap">
     <div class="row">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>               
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>               
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>               
     </div>
</div>
```

See the rest @ http://jsfiddle.net/axv7T/

Comment: If I had a few more minutes I'd remove the the box-shadow, switch over to using border-box, and set up some padding, colors, and actual borders. But this should showcase the effect you were looking for

Comment: Oh my goodness, incredible!! Yes, it seems like that is indeed what I needed, I can barely beleive my eyes that you came up with that so quickly, thank you so much Evan! :D I would upvote your comment but it seems I need 15+ reputation to do so first... else I'd upvote it 20 times if I could :P

Comment: No worries! They have me build weirder things at my job, so I'm always approaching CSS outside of the box. Feel free to PM me if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks! :D I tried to figure out how to send a PM and the only lead I found was that there's a 50 reputation requirement, so I have to send it here:
First of all thank you so much for your help, it already saved a ton of headache, I'm not entirely sure why I couldn't find the method you used anywhere online but it really looks like it could solve my problem (oh crud, now I see comments have a character limit... I hope I can post several comments in a row), I really hate to bother you for help more but I'm having a slight difficulty applying your method to my case, I'm probably overlooking som-

Comment: -ething very obvious, but I'm overviewing http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp looking for how to apply it to my situation. An example of my previous code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/3v2v2/ as you can see when the content extends in one cell the others instantly resize, while in your example seen here; http://jsfiddle.net/qBn5L/ the "cells" resize smoothly, however, I can't quite figure out how to make them resize according to the content in one of them instead of onhover ^^; I'm sure there must be some really easy way I'm overlooking...

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed your comment. After I put that together last week I tightened it up a bit here http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/hgLtD so it was relevant to height as well.

Comment: Think of it like this - cut the grid down to a row of three items. When you hover the row, all of the items within the row become a third of the total row's width. But to hover over a row - you need to be hovering an item, which becomes two thirds of the row's width at the same time.

Comment: Taking it a step further, you add a wrap, and stack two more rows. When you hover over the wrap, all of the rows become a third of the height of the total wrap's height - again, you need to be hovering a row for this to happen - so that row's height becomes two thirds of the wrap's height.